# how to deploy asp .net website alongwith database in IIS?

Tags: .net, asp.net

When I run website in browser, following server error occured -

```
Server Error in '/FinalHVA' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Cannot open database "HVAdb" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'COMP1\ASPNET'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the comp1\aspnet user doesn't have permissions to login to the HVAdb database.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your web.config file , specifically the Database Connections, it looks like the login credentials being passed to the database is the Machine\ASPNET account

A Standard Connection String will look like this:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

If you want to use the credentials of the user accessing the web application, you should use:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Note - you should disable anonymous access on the virtual directory if you would like to use a trusted connection i.e. the second one.

Comment: <connectionStrings>
<add name="HVAdbConnectionString" connectionString="DataSource=COMP1;Initial Catalog=HVAdb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

This is connection string